# Calculate the integral of the pyramid.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Calculate the integral of the pyramid.
$S_{n} = \left \{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k} \leq  a, x_{k} \geq  0, k = 1, ... , n\right \}$
$\int_{S_{n}}  \left (\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k} \right )^p dx , p\geq  0 $

can enter new variables $y_1=x_1, y_2=x_1+x_2,..., y_n=x_1+x_2+...+x_n.$ The area will be defined by the constraints $0≤y_1≤y_2≤....≤y_n≤a$. The Jacobian of this substitution is 1.
The integrand has the form $y_n$.

$\int_{0}^{a}dy_{n}\int_{0}^{y_{n}} dy_{n-1} ... \int_{0}^{y_2} y_ndy_{1}$
Is the integral written correctly?
Please tell me how to calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the $y_n$ near the end should be $y_n^p$, but apart from that it's right.

Before we solve the problem, let's lay down three [sanity checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check). By dimensional analysis, your integral must be some multiple of $a^{n+p}$. The case $n=1$ needs to get $\int_0^ay_n^pdy_n=\frac{a^{p+1}}{p+1}$. Finally, the case $p=0$ is famous; it's the hypervolume, $\frac{a^n}{n!}$. With any luck, we'll get a result honouring all these constraints.

Now evaluate the integrals innermost first (or as you've written it, from right to left). Since $\int_0^{y_2}y_n^pdy_1=y_2y_n^p$,$$\int_0^{y_3}dy_2\int_0^{y_2}y_n^pdy_1=\int_0^{y_3}dy_2y_2y_n^p=\frac12y_3^2y_n^p,$$and$$\int_0^{y_4}dy_3\int_0^{y_3}dy_2\int_0^{y_2}y_n^pdy_1=\int_0^{y_4}\frac12y_3^2y_n^pdy_3=\frac{1}{3!}y_4^3y_n^p.$$As we continue in this pattern, we eventually get$$\int_0^ady_n\int_0^{y_n}\frac{1}{(n-2)!}y_{n-1}^{n-2}y_n^pdy_{n-1}=\int_0^ady_n\frac{1}{(n-1)!}y_n^{n+p-1}=\frac{a^{n+p}}{(n-1)!(n+p)}.$$Oh, good; that passes all of our checks.